# Creating array of collections

Tags: java, arrays, collections

Java does not allow to create array of collections, shows compilation error `cannot create a generic array`

```
ArrayList<String>[] list = new ArrayList<String>[2];
```

but i can create generic collection like this

```
ArrayList<?>[] list = new ArrayList<?>[2];
```

Why there is no compiler warning in the above case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you can't create a generic array. I think the reason why this isn't allowed is because arrays are `reified` which means that the type information is known at runtime and is enforced by them. By contrast, the type information from generics is `erased` at runtime.

Because of the above, it's allowed to have something like this `T[] array = new E[size];` where E is a subtype of T.

When you use generics you aren't allowed to do something like this: `List<T> list = new ArrayList<E>();` where E is a subtype of T.

The only allowed type parrameter allowed with arrays is the `unbound wildcard ?` since this means that any type is accepted.